# Loop Through Combined List of Different Typed Objects

Tags: vb.net

I have two lists. One has the type of "Foo" the other the type of "Bar."

Foo and Bar both happen to have the property of "a."

Is there a way to loop through both of these lists combined with each other to check the value of the property a?

psuedo code

```
for each item in FooList + BarList
    if item.a = "this is the value" then
        return True
    end if
next
```

I do not want to loop through the lists separately, although I know this would work.

I do not want the original lists to be modified as a result of the appending.

Linq answers are acceptable.

---

The context is that I am searching through all the text in DXF files. Some of these texts are called MTEXTS and some are simply called TEXT. MTEXT is just a text with more features, yet both of these things obviously contain the common property of "value" no matter what the other properties are.

---

### Update

Based off the code in the accepted answer I was able to come up with a quick inline method.

```
for each item in new List(Of Object)().Concat(FooList).Concat(BarList)
    if item.a = "this is the value" then
        return True
    end if
next
```

Comment: Create an interface that has the property `a` and implement it in both classes. Then, instead of having two lists,  you can create a `List(Of TheInterface)` and iterate its items.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the classes cannot be modified. (Library)

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Do they have a common denominator? You can iterate through them as their denominator while direct casting them to see the content of `a` if so.

Comment: Then use two loops; not a big deal! If you want, you can combine both lists into one `List(Of Object)`, iterate its items and use `TryCast` to access the `a` property but that's not a good idea at all. Just use two loops.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your post in my opinion.

Comment: `both happen to have the property` lucky you. Was there any premeditation which would have caused this? Maybe the premeditator should have thought to make them implement an interface or share an abstract class with the property in question. Can you still add a `Partial Class` to the assembly in which you can make them implement said polymorphism? In a vacuum this question is ok, but to OOP professionals it stinks. That is possibly why it's not well received. I didn't downvote btw because I can look at it in a vacuum and it's... ok.

Comment: The classes extend a generic EntityObject class. MTEXT is not a TEXT, they just happen to have a similar property. DXF files consist of LINES, ARCS, DIMENSION LINES, and many more. All of these have the similar properties of start and end point but given the nature of the format, it would be pretty silly to implement an interface on these classes JUST to handle these two properties. IMO @djv

Comment: @Bigbob556677 that would not be so silly. `IDisposable` has just one method and it's one of the most used interfaces in .NET

Comment: @djv True. You have a point. Haha. I'm just thinking in the defense of the library writer. Plus this is coming from more of a scripting angle in which you arent limited to types, so you could have an array with any number of types and loop through them looking for a particular property. Thanks though

Comment: @Bigbob556677 I know how it is to work with mechanical designers who try their hand at software, so you have a pass :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this will draw the ire of many, but here is one way to do this.  Cast the Lists to Object, then Concat() them together so you can enumerate over them.  Now use CallByName() to get the "A" property from them:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private FooList As New List(Of Foo)
    Private BarList As New List(Of Bar)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FooList.Add(New Foo() With {.A = "Bob"})
        FooList.Add(New Foo() With {.A = "Dora"})
        BarList.Add(New Bar() With {.A = "Pikachu"})
        BarList.Add(New Bar() With {.A = "Aang"})
        BarList.Add(New Bar() With {.A = "Joe"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each O As Object In FooList.Cast(Of Object).Concat(BarList.Cast(Of Object))
            Dim A As String = CallByName(O, "A", CallType.Get)
            Debug.Print(A)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Foo

    Public Property A As String

End Class

Public Class Bar

    Public Property A As String

End Class
```

Comment: I think this works great, i was starting to come to the concat conclusion anyhow. This is understandably a confusing thing to do, yet in my specific case it is the ideal way for me to do it.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 Judging by your edit to the question (The paragraph _"The context..."_), this seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There are probably better solutions but you seem to have used the wrong example to demonstrate what you are _actually_ trying to do. Also, that's probably part of the reason why your question is receiving downvotes.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Granted my problem is "How do i combine two lists of different types" which is exactly what was posted, I don't see how this would qualify as an XY problem. This code isn't limited to that context, that's just the context at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is a solution using anonymous types and LINQ

```
Private foos As New List(Of Foo)
Private bars As New List(Of Bar)

Sub Main()
    foos.Add(New Foo() With {.A = "this is not the value"})
    foos.Add(New Foo() With {.A = "this is not the value"})
    bars.Add(New Bar() With {.A = "this is the value"})
    bars.Add(New Bar() With {.A = "this is not the value"})
    Console.WriteLine($"Found the value: {fooBar()}. Press any key to exit!")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function fooBar() As Boolean
    Dim combinedList = foos.Select(Function(f) New With {f.A}).Concat(bars.Select(Function(f) New With {f.A}))
    For Each item In combinedList
        If item.A = "this is the value" Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function

Public Class Foo
    Public Property A As String
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Public Property A As String
End Class
```